# Full name search with ransack and mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, mongoid, ransack

I have a mongoid documents with first_name and last_name but i need to search them with ransack by full_name. I found solution but it's only for active record, any ideas?

https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack/issues/166

Comment: use this gem https://github.com/kristianmandrup/ransack-mongoid

Comment: @TusharPal its not updated since few years, I don't think it's a good idea

Comment: you can use this gem 'ransack', github: 'Zhomart/ransack', branch: 'mongoid'